# releasing to remote repositary maven release:prepare error - pom.xml is not a working folder

Tags: svn, maven-release-plugin

Hey guys I'm trying to perform a simple mvn release. I created a simple maven project. I has just a default hello world class. When i try to perform 
mvn release:prepare -Dresume=false -Dusername=abc -Dpassword=xxx -DtagBase=https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/e-m-s/tags/

i get the following error

```
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ test ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: D:\ESM-Everything\test\target\test-1.0.jar
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 1.909s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 27 17:53:08 IST 2013
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 17M/153M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --username abhishekamte --password ***** --
no-auth-cache --non-interactive commit --file C:\Users\Abhishek\AppData\Local\Te
mp\maven-scm-508381318.commit --targets C:\Users\Abhishek\AppData\Local\Temp\mav
en-scm-8110447143629106448-targets"
[INFO] Working directory: D:\ESM-Everything\test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.355s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 27 17:53:09 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4
.1:prepare (default-cli) on project test: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] svn: E155007: 'D:\ESM-Everything\test\pom.xml' is not a working copy
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
```

An here is the pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.testrelease</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <tagNameFormat>v1.0</tagNameFormat>
      <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
      <releaseProfiles>releases</releaseProfiles>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <distributionManagement>

        <repository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>http://nexus-mvnrepo.rhcloud.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>http://nexus-mvnrepo.rhcloud.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:svn://subversion.assembla.com/svn/e-m-s/trunks/</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:svn://subversion.assembla.com/svn/e-m-s/trunks/</developerConnection>
        <url>svn://subversion.assembla.com/svn/e-m-s/trunks/</url>
    </scm> 


</project>
```

I have googled all the solutions but couldnt get any way around the problem. 
Thanks